# Finding iterators to any of two elemens in a container

Tags: search, find

I want to find iterators to any of two elements in a container. For instance I have a vector of **{1, 2, 3, 4}** and I want to search for elements **2** or **5** in it (each one of them found first is OK, because my container only contains one of them or none of them). I am using two std::find to look for each of two elements (**2** and **5**), but is there a more efficient method?

Thank you,
Shahab

Comment: try to show us what you have tried!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use std::find to search for the two elements twice, it can be done by searching only once. The problem is that std::find returns as soon as a single value is found, so it can't be used on multiple values.

```
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (*first==val) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}
```

the solution to this would be creating your own loop to traverse your list and checking if  the list contains (a || b)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I use std::any_of for searching two elements?